# Converting a ndarrary back to 1-d array

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, scikit-learn

I have a 1-d array of class labels. As follows(e.g):

```
Y
array([16, 34,  1,  1, 35,  1,  1, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 34,  7, 21, 30,
       16, 16, 21, 21, 20, 20, 16, 23, 23,  4, 23, 21, 16, 20, 33, 16, 16,
       16, 34, 21, 34, 34,  1,  1, 16, 16, 34, 23, 34, 16, 34, 23,  1, 20,
        1, 20, 21, 21, 35, 36, 16, 16, 16, 33, 16, 21, 16, 16, 16, 36,  7,
       25, 16, 16, 16, 34, 33, 20, 20, 16, 20, 16, 34, 36, 20, 20, 16, 13,
       16, 20, 20, 21,  1, 20, 20, 16, 16, 33, 16, 16, 21, 35, 20, 16, 16
```

The no. of records are ~21K.

Each unique value represents a class of an object. Multi-class setting with 37 unique classes.

Now I binaries these labels so that I can use it in One Vs All Multi-class setting.

I do as follows:

```
Y=label_binarize(Y, classes=range(len(class_mapping)))
```

Here class_mapping is a dict of text class names to numeric class values mapping. Length of that gives me the total no. of classes so this way I binaries my class values from 1-D array to n-d array.

Now if I want to go back to my original 1-d array from the same n-d array, how do I do that?

Edit: code to do random forest

```
def RF(k_fold,train_X,train_Y):
        """Method to implement Multi-class RandomForest"""

        from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
        scores_rf = []

        for train_indices, test_indices in k_fold:
            train_X_cv = train_X[train_indices]
            train_Y_cv= train_Y[train_indices]

            test_X_cv = train_X[test_indices]
            test_Y_cv= train_Y[test_indices]

            rf=RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=150,criterion='entropy')
            scores_rf.append(rf.fit(train_X_cv,train_Y_cv).score(test_X_cv,test_Y_cv))

        print("The mean accuracy of Random Forests on CV data is:", np.mean(scores_rf))

        return rf


def test_performance(test_X,test_Y,classifier,name):
        """This method checks the performance of each algorithm on test data."""

        from sklearn import metrics

        # For SGD
        print ("The accuracy of "+ name + " on test data is:",classifier.score(test_X,test_Y))
        print ('Classification Metrics for '+ name+ ' :')
        print metrics.classification_report(test_Y, classifier.predict(test_X))
        print "Confusion matrix"
        print metrics.confusion_matrix(test_Y, classifier.predict(test_X))   



def plot_ROC(test_X,test_Y,classifier,name):
    """ This functions plots the ROC curve of the classifier"""

    fig=plt.figure(figsize=(15,9))

    from sklearn.metrics import roc_curve, auc
    if name in ['rf','sgd_svm']:
        Y_score=classifier.predict_proba(test_X).T[1]
    else:
        Y_score = classifier.decision_function(test_X)


    n_classes = len(class_mapping)

    # Compute ROC curve and ROC area for each class
    fpr = dict()
    tpr = dict()
    roc_auc = dict()
    for i in range(n_classes):
        fpr[i], tpr[i], _ = roc_curve(test_Y[:, i], Y_score[:, i])
        roc_auc[i] = auc(fpr[i], tpr[i])

    # Compute micro-average ROC curve and ROC area
    fpr["micro"], tpr["micro"], _ = roc_curve(test_Y.ravel(), Y_score.ravel())
    roc_auc["micro"] = auc(fpr["micro"], tpr["micro"])


    ##############################################################################
    # Plot ROC curves for the multiclass problem

    # Compute macro-average ROC curve and ROC area

    # First aggregate all false positive rates
    all_fpr = np.unique(np.concatenate([fpr[i] for i in range(n_classes)]))

    # Then interpolate all ROC curves at this points
    mean_tpr = np.zeros_like(all_fpr)
    for i in range(n_classes):
        mean_tpr += interp(all_fpr, fpr[i], tpr[i])

    # Finally average it and compute AUC
    mean_tpr /= n_classes

    fpr["macro"] = all_fpr
    tpr["macro"] = mean_tpr
    roc_auc["macro"] = auc(fpr["macro"], tpr["macro"])

    # Plot all ROC curves
    plt.figure()
    plt.plot(fpr["micro"], tpr["micro"],
         label='micro-average ROC curve (area = {0:0.2f})'
               ''.format(roc_auc["micro"]),
         linewidth=2)

    plt.plot(fpr["macro"], tpr["macro"],
         label='macro-average ROC curve (area = {0:0.2f})'
               ''.format(roc_auc["macro"]),
         linewidth=2)

    for i in range(n_classes):
        plt.plot(fpr[i], tpr[i], label='AUC class {0} (area = {1:0.2f})'
                                   ''.format(i, roc_auc[i]))

    plt.plot([0, 1], [0, 1], 'k--')
    plt.xlim([0.0, 1.0])
    plt.ylim([0.0, 1.05])
    plt.xlabel('False Positive Rate')
    plt.ylabel('True Positive Rate')
    plt.title('Multi-Class ROC Curve of '+name)
    plt.legend(loc="lower right")
```

To plot multi-class ROC i need to have labels binariezed but to have classification metrics in test_performance function I need the labels back as 1-d array.

Comment: You should be able to directly assign back to pandas using `Y` it's shouldn't be necessary to convert I think

Comment: @EdChum as in?. The problem is I had a Y target values as 1-d array of all class categories. I label_binarized it and then did k-fold cross validation. So now my Test_Y is binary_labelized. 

However if I need to do any classification metrics from sklearn I need to have it as actual 1-d array for the same Test_Y. So how do I convert a matrix of binary_labelized back to 1-d Array

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood you're generating a binary class vector for classification, so you have somewhere a list of the 37 unique classes and you want to convert back to your original class labels from the binary representation?

Comment: @EdChum Well I am doing a multi-class classification. I have 37 unique classes. My label vector is Y which is 37 unique classes spread over 78K odd observations. Now to do multi-class classification I binarize my classes using label_binarize. So now it gives me 78k X 37 matrix. 

To this matrix I pass it to a train_test split function and then to a k-fold on the train_Y data. So now I have a Test_Y matrix which has test values of the order 21k X 37. This is used for making Roc curve where i need binarised labels. However for classification_metrics I need the 1-d array of Test_Y .

Comment: It depends on your classifier algorithm, you've not specified your algorithm or model but some work fine out of the box with multi-class data

Comment: @EdChum Pls see the edit and the code of algo

Comment: random forest already supports multi-class data, you don't need to binary label the classes

Comment: To plot multi-class ROC curve i would need to binarize right?

Comment: but how are you going to determine the binary classes for `ROC` here? The plot expects only 2 classes, positive/negative how does this apply to 37 classes? Are you sure this is right kind of plot to consider?

Comment: I am following the plot for multi-class classification as mentioned here: 

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_roc.html#example-model-selection-plot-roc-py. 

I need to get AUC value for comparing multi-class models. Without ROC how do I get AUC?. Accuracy and other stuff doesn't make much sense. Pls advise

Comment: You should be able to follow that example using your code, there is no requirement there to convert back to a 2-d array

Comment: Yes there is no requirement there to convert back to 1-d array. But for classification metrics and confusion metrics I need to convert back as shown in the code above

Comment: You should be able to reconstruct by comparing the ordinal position for the binary label with the unique real class label in your data so something like `dict(zip(range(n_classes), np.unique(Y)))`

Comment: @EdChum Hmm.. Makes sense. Quick question on the same. In random forest when I run Y_score=classifier.predict_proba(test_X)

It is just giving me a list of 37 values. Whereas what I need is a matrix of [n_samples,n_classes]. It does say in docs it should give n_samples, n_classes but I get only a list of 37 values

Comment: that returns the probability prediction for all 37 classes for that specific row, so the highest probability score is the one it thinks is the most likely class

Comment: Ok. But if i want to get for each row and each class a prob score?. Like n_samples, n_class matrix. How do I get it in Random forest? Docs says it should give that. But i get just a list of 37 values for whole of test data

Comment: You want [predict](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html#sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.predict) if you want a single class label returned

Comment: Predict will give me only single class label. What I want is that if i have 10 test sample and I have 37 classes then i should get a matrix of 10X37. With prob values for each class for that sample

Comment: then you need to pass 10 rows, you should debug that side, check the shape of the data you're passing, it sounds like you're passing a single row

Comment: No I am passing whole matrix. 

Y_score=rf.predict_proba(test_X)


test_X:

(21348, 21)